# Duplicate class go.Seq found in modules jetified-packageone-runtime (packageone.aar) and jetified-packagetwo-runtime (packagetwo.aar)

Tags: android, go, gomobile

I am trying to use two different go packages in my android app project

I am using gomobile and each package is compiled with

```
gomobile bind --target=android
```

They are imported like this

```
implementation files("libs/packageone.aar")
implementation files("libs/packagetwo.aar")
```

and they work separateley, but they conflict when i try to run the app.

and I get the following error

```
Duplicate class go.Seq found in modules jetified-packageone-runtime (packageone.aar) and jetified-packagetwo-runtime (packagetwo.aar)
```

Comment: It means that `go.Seq` class exists in both packages; and this confuses android studio when it comes to building the project

Comment: Yes but I guess `go.Seq` is generated by gomobile, and I don't know what I can do about it else than merging the 2 libraries into eachother before I import them to the android project.

Answer (score 1):

I made an issue and got this response:

> Unfortunately, that won't work.
>
> The recommended workaround is to bind both packageone and packagetwo at once, and build one .aar.

https://github.com/golang/go/issues/56567